# Forking or cloning a private gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a gem in my Gemfile which reads from a custom source, and requires authentication -- as below:

```
source "https://gems.xxxxx.com/gems" do
  gem "xyz", "~> 1.2.4"
end
```

I want to remove the dependancy on this provider and on the "remote" gem, incase something happens to the remote source.

Is there a way for me to fork/clone a private gem (I have authentication details), and host it myself?

Comment: Make sure that the self-hosted gem is private too.

Answer (score 1):

> Bundler allows you to configure credentials for any gem source, which allows you to avoid putting secrets into your Gemfile.

```
$ bundle config xxxxx.com username:password
```

See [the documentation for the bundle config command](https://bundler.io/v1.15/bundle_config.html). You can also use an ENV var:

```
export BUNDLE_GEMS__XXXXX__COM="username:password"
```

This is per domain (not sure how it works with subdomains). If you need to set credentials for a specific repo use:

```
bundle config https://gems.xxxxx.com/gems/awesome_gem.git username:password
```

> Is there a way for me to fork/clone a private gem (I have authentication details), and host it myself?

**Yes.** Provided you can access a git repo then you should be able to clone it (practically - not legally). Forking is actually a workflow and not a specific command so the the details may vary depending on the host. Github allows you to fork private repo's which enables the fork & pull model - your fork might not actually be private by default and you may need to pay to be able to make it private.  With bundler you can provide gems from either your local machine or any http(s) address.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way this is possible, without necessarily cloning it:

1. Look in your Gemfile for the gem name.
2. Run: gem unpack  --target vendor/gems
3. Take a look in the vendor/gems directory and see what the vendored gem directory name is for the next step.
4. Update the Gemfile to point the gem reference to the newly vendored gem path.

gem '', 'VERSION_NUMBER_GOES_HERE', path:
"vendor/gems/"

5. Run: bundle update

This will remove the reliance on the remote vendor and store it locally, although it will not receive version updates.